# In Xamarin, pass the received Intent from another app between different activities in the same app

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have two actions in the Xamarin App (Splash Screen Activity: `com.example.splashactivity`, and Main Activity: `com.example.mainactivity`).

In a normal scenario: the splash screen appears when the app initially launches, displaying a short animation before redirecting to the main activity.

**SplashActivity.cs**

```
[Activity(Name = "com.example.splashactivity")]
public class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity, Animator.IAnimatorListener
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Code

        // Redirects to MainActivity
        StartActivity(new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(MainActivity)));
    }
}
```

But when an intent is sent from another app (let's call it **Second App**), the main activity is immediately opened without any animation (obviously, `com.example.mainactivity` is called).

Now, when I put the splash activity's name (`com.example.splashactivity`) into the **Second App**, it launches the splash screen and then redirects to the main activity. I keep the Intent Values in SecureStorage since I require them throughout the app.

When I was done with the operation, I sent a message (`MessagingCenter.Send<object>()`) to Splash Activity and gave it data to send back in Intent Extra, but it remained stuck there (no redirection to Second App)

```
[Activity(Name = "com.example.splashactivity")]
public class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity, Animator.IAnimatorListener
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Receive Intent from Second App
        string id = Intent.GetStringExtra("id");
        if (Intent.HasExtra("id"))
        {
            await SecureStorage.SetAsync("Intent_id", id);
        }

        // Sends Intent Extra Back to Second App
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object>(this, "IntentBack", async (e) =>
        {
            var msg = await SecureStorage.GetAsync("IntentBack_msg");

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionMain);
            intent.PutExtra("msg", msg);
            SetResult(Result.Ok, intent);
            Finish();
        });

        // Redirects to MainActivity
        StartActivity(new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(MainActivity)));
    }
}
```

Comment: `I sent a message (MessagingCenter.Send<object>()) to Splash Activity and gave it data to send back in Intent Extra, but it remained stuck there`  Where did you send the message?

Comment: There are two Activities in my Xamarin App (**SplashActivity** & **MainActivity**). The job of SplashActivity is to show the Splash Screen and then redirect to MainActivity. `StartActivity(new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(MainActivity)));`.

Comment: When **Another App** sends an Intent to *Xamarin App*, it opens *SplashActivity*, shows the splash screen, stores the intent in `SecureStorage` (sent from another app), and redirects to *MainActivity*. In **Xamarin.Forms**, the values of an intent are gotten from `SecureStorage` and the actions are performed on them. When everything is done, a message from *Xamarin.Forms* are being sent to *MainActivity* by `MessagingCenter.Send()`, which then redirects to *SplashActivity* via `Intent(this, typeof(SplashActivity)));`.

Comment: When a message to *SplashActivity* is received from *MainActivity*, it should send an Intent Extra back to *Another App* via `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionMain);` `intent.PutExtra("success", success);` `SetResult(Result.Ok, intent);` `Finish();`, but it became stuck there and doesn't redirect to *Another App*.

Comment: I suspect SplashActivity is Disposed when MainActivity is started. If I'm right, then the Subscribe would be "lost" when SplashActivity goes away. Use either `Bundle` parameter of `StartActivity`, or `PutExtra` parameters of the Intent that starts MainActivity. Either way, `MainActivity` will need to prep the IntentBack from data passed in to it.